# PHPStorm / FileWatcher - automatic deploy of grunt processed files

Tags: gruntjs, phpstorm

I've configured some grunt tasks (concat/uglify) that generates minified files in my project. These tasks are triggered with the File Watcher plugin that comes with PHPStorm.
I've also configured automatic deployment, but that does not work for files that have been generated by grunt tasks.

I thought this would be handled by the "Output paths to refresh" option in the File Watcher (where I specified the full path to the minified file), but this does not trigger the automatic deploy.

Have I forgotten something? Please help.

Comment: checking `upload external changes` under `tools > deployment > options` solved this problem for me when running grunt manually from an external command-line. however, i need to switch to a different window and then switch back to phpStorm to trigger this.